# Acer Veriton N281G,processor and HDD goes 100%

Tags: windows-10, process

I have **Acer Veriton N281G 4GB RAM intel Atom D425 1.80Ghz HDD 320GB** installed windows 10.

> i have installed a clean windows but when start up prossessor and HDD go to 100% i dont understand why.any idea why
>   [image: hdd]

[image: processor]

Comment: Have you examined task manager while this occurs?  Are any processes eating up these resources?  Which ones?

Comment: i post 2 fotos see

Comment: It appears that Antimalware Service Executable is what is causing the CPU usage and is also contributing to the Disk usage.  The System and Compressed Memory process is also using the disk a lot also.  I would examine the Antimalware process first, as the System and Compressed memory process is part of Windows.  Perhaps look into Windows Defender.  Also, toggle the arrow for that process and see what else is under it.

Comment: but when cpu goes to 40 % or under when i open for example edge it going again 100 processor and hdd.

Comment: try a different Av suite (AvastFree for example)

Comment: Do you have a bunch of tabs open in Edge from your last session?  Understand an Atom processor (1 core) is not that good of a processor compared to a new i7 (4 cores) for instance and it is going to max out pretty easily. Atom: http://ark.intel.com/products/49489/Intel-Atom-Processor-D425-512K-Cache-1_80-GHz  i7:  http://ark.intel.com/products/88200/Intel-Core-i7-6700T-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz  A virus scan will bog down a harddrive that is not SSD and yes tie up your single core processor

Comment: but for this parameters is good for windows 10